# How to show that switching the ring of integers for the field of rationals will yield a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Given:

> $( \{a+b \sqrt{n}\,|\,a,b\in \mathbb{Z} \},+,\times)$ and $( \{a+bi\sqrt{n}\,|\,a,b\in \mathbb{Z} \},+,\times)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.
>
> Show that in the given example, if we switch the ring of the integers
> for the field of rational numbers (e.g if we take $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$)
> we will obtain fields.

I proceded from the definition of a field:

> A field is a ring $(K,+,\times)$ that has an inverse multiplicative
> for every $n\in K\neq 0$ so that $x\times y=1$.

I thought that the demonstration consist in finding a $y$ such that $(a+b \sqrt{n})\times y=1$, solving for $y$, I'll obtain:

$$y=\frac{1}{a+b \sqrt{n}}$$

Which is a rational number for some $n$'s, is that correct? I'm starting to doubt it because I guess for some $n$'s (e.g. $n=2$), we'll have a real number.

Comment: Hint: $(a+b\sqrt{n})(a-b\sqrt{n}) = a^2-b^2n \in \mathbb Q$

Comment: I guess there is a typo in $\{a+b>i\sqrt n|\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need $y$ itself to be rational (that usually isn't possible). You need $y$ to be of the form $$c+d\sqrt n$$ for some rationals $c,d$. In the case that $n$ isn't a perfect square, try rationalizing the denominator of $$y=\frac1{a+b\sqrt n}$$ to find this form of $y$. If $n$ **is** a perfect square, then the structure should be far more familiar. (What is it?)

Comment: I don't understand: How is $c+d\sqrt n$ the multiplicative inverse of $a+b\sqrt n$?

Comment: Assuming that $n$ isn't a perfect square, set $(a+b\sqrt n)(c+d\sqrt n)=1.$  solve the resulting system for $c$ and $d$. Show that both are rational.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no need to do this separately: just take $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the two cases can be treated in the same way.

The simple case is when $n$ is a perfect square: $n=m^2$. Then the set you want to verify to be a field is just $\mathbb{Q}$.

So we can assume that $n$ is not a square. Therefore

$$
a^2 - nb^2\ne0
$$

for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Otherwise

$$
n=\biggl(\frac{a}{b}\biggr)^2
$$

which is impossible. (Proof?)

Next, consider

$$
y=\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{n}}
$$

that you know is defined in $\mathbb{C}$; we want to reduce it to the form $y=c+d\sqrt{n}$ where $c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$. Just observe that

$$
y=\frac{a-b\sqrt{n}}{a^2-nb^2}
$$

and that the denominator is non zero. Therefore

$$
c=\frac{a}{a^2-nb^2},\qquad d=\frac{-b}{a^2-nb^2}
$$

are the rational numbers you wanted.

Also you should check closure for addition and multiplication, which are easy.